# Retrieving request parameters (such as controller and action) in Kohana 3.2

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I have my controllers with the following extensions:

Controller_Login extends Controller_Layout
Controller_Layout extends Controller_Template

so that all controllers (processing user urls) will pass through Controller_Layout. In my controller_Layout, I'm trying to retrieve the controller and action url values in order to bind them and display them in my layout view.

Calling this `echo $this->request->param('controller');` returns nothing (empty string), while calling `echo $this->request->param();` return an empty array. Clearly nothing is found in the request.

I'm wondering if this is because I'm trying to retrieve the request values from the parent controller of where the request is actually handled. Idealy i'd like to handle this through my parent controller (controller_Layout) since every page request will need to make this call to retrieve the controller and action value

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current Requests controller name, use `$this->request->controller()` instead of `$this->request->param('controller')`. Same goes for current action, they aren't variable parameters so they're accessed this way.

And yes, you can handle those in the parent controller, keep it DRY :)

Comment: Yup that worked! I've tried using the controller() call before, but i must have used it in the wrong function call; seems that if i put it in the before() function, it works fine, but i get all these errors when i place it in my action_index() function call of my controller_Layout... would you know why?

And what do you mean by keeping it dry? As in not too much value manipulation?

Comment: @user751564 DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself